# MVC3 DropDownList Code First

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, model, drop-down-menu, ef-code-first

I have the following MVC3 model:

```
public class Dine
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Table Number")]
    public string TableNumber { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> TableSelections { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Table Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

}
```

}

The List items values are defined in the controller and the dropdownlist is displayed fine in the view just when submit is pressed to save the value to the database I get the following error:

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

It is based on this tutorial http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/dropdown-lists-in-mvc-3/

Thanks

EDIT
I have followed the suggestions from below and get this error: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

This is what I have in my view:

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableSelection, (SelectList)ViewBag.Tables)</td>
```

This is what I have in my model

```
public class Dine
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Table No")]
    public int TableNo { get; set; }

    public string TableOption { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Table Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public class RestaurantController : Controller
{
    TheDatabaseEntities db = new TheDatabaseEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Dine/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        ViewBag.Tables = GetTableOptions();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Restaurant model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("AddBookingComplete");
        }
        ViewBag.Tables = GetTableOptions();

        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult BookingComplete()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private List<Restaurant> GetTableOptions()
    {
        List<Restaurant> Tables = new List<Restaurant>();
        Table.Add(new Dine() { TableNumber = 1, TableSelection = "Table 1" });
        Table.Add(new Dine() { TableNumber = 2, TableOSelection = "Table" });
        Table.Add(new Dine() { TableNumber = 3, TableSelection = "Table" });
        Tables.Add(new Dine() { TableNumber = 4, TableSelection = "Table" });

        return Table;
        }
}
}
```

Any help is appriciated as I am very new to MVC3 Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

No, You do not have an MVC3 Model.  You have an Entity Framework model that you are trying to use as an MVC3 model.  This is not a subtle distinction.

You are adding a select list to your Entity Framework model, thus Entity Framework is trying to serialize it to the database.  Don't do that.  Use Entity Models for Data, use View Models for MVC.

You claim what you are doing is based on a tutorial, but nowhere in that tutorial do you see them using an Entity Framework model.  It's a View Model.

If you insist on using your EF model in your view (despite best practice saying don't do that), then you need to pass your SelectList via ViewData (or ViewBag), not in your model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do I make it into a viewmodel then? sorry I am very new to MVC

Answer (score 0):

Mystere Man is right. I'm gonna guess you need to save a selected value from a dropdown list to the database. If so, change the TableOption property by something like this:

```
public string TableOption { get; set; }
```

Then, in your controler pass the SelectList object to your view using ViewBag as Mystery said:

```
ViewBag.Tables = yourList;
```

And in your view use a dropdown helper to fill the select and bind to model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableOption, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tables, "TableNo","TableOption"))
```

Finally save your model in your post action method.

Comment: ok thanks both of you for your help, suppose I did it this way http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/dropdown-lists-in-mvc-3/ using a viewmodel then how would I save the values to the database? I usually do it like this: if (ModelState.IsValid) { db.Order.Add(order); db.SaveChanges(); }

Comment: You can use your EF model as a View model. Actually this is one of the advantage of code-first approach. What you are doing wrong here is try to put a list of SelectListItem into your entity (Restaurant class). This is interpreted by EF as if you had a One-to-Many relationship between Restaurant table and SelectListItem table (and you don't have a SelectListItem table). So, if you want to use your EF model as View model, you must do what I'm suggesting in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I have followed your suggestion but get the following error: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList', I have also updated the question above to show my current status of work. Do you knwo why this error is occuring?

Comment: I was guessing that GetTableTypes returned a SelectList object and not a List<Restaurant>. You have 3 options: 1. Change the GetTableTypes method to return a SelectList object. or 2. Get a SelectList from your list of restaurants: ViewBag.Tables = new SelectList(GetTableTypes(), "TableNo", "TableOption"); or 3. You can do the same directly into your view: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TableOption, new SelectList(ViewBag.Tables, "TableNo", "TableOption"))